# TikZ: How to add an arrow tip to an arc drawn with the pic syntax?

Tags: tikz-pgf, technical-drawing, engineering, stanli

This question continues my [another](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/404244/how-to-draw-over-an-picture-in-tikz).

My code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}

\usetikzlibrary{
                angles,
                quotes
               }

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    %the points
    \point{right above}{3}{1.5};
    \point{above}{1}{2};
    \point{below}{0}{0};

    %the hairline
    \draw
      (above) -- (below);

    %the coordinate system
    \draw
      [
       <->,
       dashed
      ] (2.25, 2) node[above] {$x$} -| node[
                                            sloped,
                                            above,
                                            at end
                                           ] {$z$} (1, 0);

    %the arc between the axes (for the pic syntax see page 255 of the TikZ & PGF manual)
    \coordinate (A) at (below);
    \coordinate (B) at (above);
    \coordinate (C) at (1, 0);
    \pic[
         draw,
         angle radius = 10mm,
         angle eccentricity = .75,
         "$\varphi$"
        ] {angle};

    %hinged support
    \support{1}{above}[180];
    \hinge{1}{above};

    %the mass
    \node[
          circle,
          draw,
          fill = white
         ] at (below) {$m$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

produces:

[image: result]

I wish:

[image: wish]

How can I do it?

Thank you for your effort in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure if this is the syntax but works:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{stanli}

\usetikzlibrary{
                angles,
                quotes
               }

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    %the points
    \point{right above}{3}{1.5};
    \point{above}{1}{2};
    \point{below}{0}{0};

    %the hairline
    \draw
      (above) -- (below);

    %the coordinate system
    \draw
      [
       <->,
       dashed
      ] (2.25, 2) node[above] {$x$} -| node[
                                            sloped,
                                            above,
                                            at end
                                           ] {$z$} (1, 0);

    %the arc between the axes (for the pic syntax see page 255 of the TikZ & PGF manual)
    \coordinate (A) at (below);
    \coordinate (B) at (above);
    \coordinate (C) at (1, 0);
    \pic[
         draw,<-, %HERE
         angle radius = 10mm,
         angle eccentricity = .75,
         "$\varphi$"
        ] {angle};

    %hinged support
    \support{1}{above}[180];
    \hinge{1}{above};

    %the mass
    \node[
          circle,
          draw,
          fill = white
         ] at (below) {$m$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I mean that the syntax for arrows in tikz, uses `->` or `-latex` etc... But I haven't use \pic yet...

Comment: Hello @koleygr! Thank you for your answer! That's an easy one!